# Cakephp, validate multiple models manually

Tags: php, validation, cakephp, models

I have a form that produces the following array upon submition (see below).
I am using this data in my controller to perform several operations, after which I save each one individually. (Saving them all at once is not an option).
What I would need to do is to find a way to validate each of this models.
I have tried already:

```
$this->Model->set($pertinentData);
$this->Model2->set($pertinentData);
if($this->Model->validates() && $this->Model2->validates()){
    //Do whatever
}
```

This produces unaccurate results, says it validates when I can see it doesn't and viceversa.

Anybody has any idea of a viable option? Ain't there a way to create a tableless model where I can define validation rules for these fields like:

```
Order.package_id
User.first_name
etc...
```

Any idea is appreciated. Below the array that the form produces.
Thanks.

```
Array
(
[Order] => Array
    (
        [id] => 15
        [package_id] => 1743
        [tariff_id] => 5470
        [tarjeta] => 332
        [numero_tarjeta] => 121204045050
        [vencimiento_tarjeta] => 10/20
        [cod_tarjeta] => 170
        [titular_tarjeta] => JESUS CRISTO
        [tarjeta_nacimiento] => 22/04/1988
        [tarjeta_pais] => Argentina
        [tarjeta_provincia] => Buenos Aires
        [tarjeta_ciudad] => Ciudad
        [tarjeta_cp] => 1428
        [tarjeta_calle] => Calle
        [tarjeta_numero] => 1477
        [tarjeta_piso] => 2
    )

[User] => Array
    (
        [id] => 
        [email] => bla8@gmail.com
        [phone] => 1568134449
        [first_name] => Jesus
        [last_name] => Something
        [documento_tipo] => dni
        [dni] => 335556666
        [nacionalidad] => argentino
        [birthdate] => 22/04/2019
    )

[OrdersCompanion] => Array
    (
        [1] => Array
            (
                [first_name] => Chango
                [last_name] => Mas
                [documento_tipo] => dni
                [dni] => 445556666
                [nacionalidad] => argentino
                [birthdate] => 30/02/2010
            )
        [1] => Array
            (
                [first_name] => Chango
                [last_name] => Mas
                [documento_tipo] => dni
                [dni] => 445556666
                [nacionalidad] => argentino
                [birthdate] => 30/02/2010
            )

    )

)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can usea tableless model by defining `$useTable= false` in the model. Like this

```
public $useTable = false;
```

Define all your custom validation and, of course, your schema (since your model has no table you have to define manually the model schema). Then in your controller, you must first indicate that it has no model, and then declare the `$model` variable. This is to avoid the automatic model-controller binding of cakePHP, your controller would look like this

```
public $useModel = false;
$model = ClassRegistry::init('ContactOperation');
```

Now your model is related to your controller as you want, and you can easily make your custom validation, previously defined.

```
$model->set($this->request->data);
    if($model->validates()) {
        $this->Session->setFlash(_('Thank you!'));
        // do email sending and possibly redirect
        // elsewhere for now, scrub the form
        // redirect to root '/'.
        unset($this->request->data);
        $this->redirect('/');
    } else {
        $this->Session->setFlash(_('Errors occurred.'));
        // display the form with errors.
    }
```

You can find more detail from [here](http://trevweb.me.uk/models-without-tables-in-cakephp/)

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
This was my original idea. However, if you check at the array I posted...how do I go about defining validation rules for Order.first_name && OrdersCompanion.first_name?

Comment: You would have to use custom validation rules. You can use custom function to make validation. If you need any data from other models you can import the models, or define relationship between your tableless model and the other models, then in your custom function use the `$this` var to refere to your model or `$this->Model` to reference other model. Check [here](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/data-validation.html#adding-your-own-validation-methods)